# Secured webservices are not working in Android emulator while the same is working on a web browser

Tags: android, emulation, hybrid

I have created a project with jQuery Mobile and Jersey web services. When I run the project in the browser, I am able to access the web service link which is run over HTTPS.

I have created an Android project with a login screen and integrated the above project which will have search functionality and hit the web service and return back the response in an html.

When I run this Android project on an emulator, I am able to login and when I click on particular search,I am not getting the corresponding web service response.

But when I point to the localhost IP address, it works.

Even I have added CORS in config.xml too:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

Comment: If you are able to login , then the problem is not with your SSL certificate other wise the handshake should have failed if that would be the reason.Try to add search response or log

Comment: When I click on Search, the ajax function is being called where as the  control is not going to the success block and going to the error block with error status code 0.

Comment: There is the problem with your ajax

Comment: The same code works when run on a browser

Comment: what error you are getting with ajax. did you debugged it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below method when you calling your WebServices, to call it you must need HttpClient object, so just get HttpClient object using below method.

```
public static List<Cookie> cookies;
public DefaultHttpClient getHttpclient() {
        if (!isHTTPSEnabled()) {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpclient.getParams(), false);

            if (cookies != null) {
                int size = cookies.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookies.get(i));
                }
            }
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
            return httpclient;
        } else {
            try {
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry);
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, httpParameters);
                HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpclient.getParams(), false);

                if (cookies != null) {
                    int size = cookies.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookies.get(i));
                    }
                }
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
                return httpclient;

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pratik for the answer. But I am very much confused where to add the above code in my project. I am calling the webservice from my jquery mobile html page in an ajax function.

Comment: @PallaviAkuthota ohhh sorry dear, I only knows native programming, not in cross platform, but as I know, when you calling your method of Http Request, just before that you have to call this.